# VIN Decoding API

Tags: javascript, css, json, html

I'm trying to create an internal VIN Decoding website that pulls data from an external site. I have the link to the API, I have the API key but the results I get after entering VIN is in JSON format.

Link Example:

https://api.mywebsite.com/api/vehicle/vins/4T1BK1EB6DU056165?&fmt=json&api_key=mykey

First question is, how do I trigger the submit button to request decode of the vin entered in the text box, into the link example shown above. The only field that will change on the link will be the VIN which in this case is represented by 4T1BK1EB6DU056165.

```
<input id="id1" type="vin" max="17">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```

And once I get the response in JSON, how do I display the code with styling in html? I tried the following code but no results:

```
function setup() { 
loadJSON("https://api.mywebsite.com/api/vehicle/vins/4T1BK1EB6DU056165?&fmt=json&api_key=mykey", gotData, 'jsonp);
```

Comment: This doesn't really look like PHP or Java. Did you mean JavaScript?

Comment: I'm assuming..sorry..I'm not a web guy...just trying to help a boss as we dont have the budget to hire someone...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone from another forum helped me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction(vin) {
        if(vin != "") {
            var url = "https://api.mysite.com/api/vehicle/v2/vins/";
            url += vin + "?fmt=json&api_key=mykey";
            window.location.href = url;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: I am looking for a site with such an api, do you still have this working ? What I need is an API where I can drop a VIN number and it will return me the brand, model, dimensions and fuell type. It is not a problem if this a not a free site.